# Simple problem about Laplace Equation in a domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that "$u$", is solution of the problem $$\triangle u=0, r<R $$ $$u_{r}(R,\phi)=f(\phi), 0<\phi\ < 2 \pi$$

Show that $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}{f(\phi)d\phi}=0$$

I know what this question seem very simple, but I need a help, I recently learned this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are told to prove that $\int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi)\>d\phi=0$ is a *necessary condition* for the existence of a solution.

A hint:

Apply Gauss' Theorem (also called Divergence Theorem) to the vector field ${\bf v}:=\nabla u$ defined on the closed disk $B_R:=\{(x,y)\>|\>x^2+y^2\leq R^2\}$.